# Html multiple video tags

Tags: html, video

I want to include a video animation for my website using the  tag in html5.  I saw that http://www.wildstar-online.com/en/ also include a video animation on their website.  My question is why would they include 3 video sources (`video/mp4`, `video/ogg`, `video/webm`)?  I used `video/mp4` for my website and it worked for almost all the major browsers.  So what is the purpose of including 3 sources of video?

Answer (score 1):

"Multiple source files can be specified using the  element in order to provide video or audio encoded in different formats for different browsers...  this allows the browser to make even more intelligent decisions"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: would that slow my page down? since it has to lead 3 sources of video?

Comment: No. The browser would determine the best source and use that, ignoring the others.